# REST Service design for Authentication

Tags: authentication, rest

I want to design REST service for authentication and account management. Please let me know whether the following satisfies the REST style.

```
POST http://server/security/authenticate?username=xxx&password=yyy
POST http://server/security/forgotPassword?username=xxx&email=yyy
PUT  http://server/security/changePassword?oldPassword=xxx&newPassword=yyy
```

Whether HTTP methods POST & PUT are right here? Since authentication doesn't modify anything, is it better to use GET here? I am confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't do that. Do not, for any reason, put the password in the URL.

In this case, I am a little confused about what you're trying to do--in general the authentication/authorization in a REST API is not handled by the resources themselves, but if you're designing a separate authentication API, perhaps this makes sense. The simple answer is, put the authentication data in the body of your requests, and send them over SSL. So

```
 POST https://server/security/changePassword/
```

and have the data in the body. And ensure the user has to authenticate within your service!

From a REST design perspective, think of the POST as a service that performs operations on the body. Ideally, have it respond with 200/201 status and a Location header with the URL of  the created/modified resource.

PUT is intended to be used when the URL (and not the query parameters) contains the location where the resource is to be created.

Arguably, it would be a restful move to do

```
GET https://server/security/{username}/{email}/forgottonPassword/
```

but that's a bit of an abuse... Stick with the posts.

If you are trying to have authentication on your resources, the Authorization  header(misnamed, but the one to use) is the place for those.

The standard restful way to do username/password authentication in this case is called [Basic Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Example)

Answer (score 4):

When modelling a REST style service you think in resources. The resource is a `user`. The services (bad because thinking in services forces an RPC style) you want to expose are authenticate and getting a security token that can be later used in an Authorization HTTP header, a password forgotten and change password functionality.

First we model the resource user which is always reachable under the base URL

```
https://server/user/{username}
```

To authenticate we need some security token so we could issue a POST to a sub resource of user that creates a security token:

```
POST https://server/user/{username}/securityToken
```

This issues a new security token that we can use in an HTTP Authorization header. I'm issuing a a `POST` request here because we model the securityToken as some kind of sub resource of user `user/someusername/securityToken`. You could use the sub resources created under security token to expose a functionality to the user to see all successful or failed login requests.

Next we want to request a forgotten password. The important thing here is `request`. That means we issue a request and create a new password forgotten request sub resource of the user. For creating sub resources, REST style uses a `POST`:

```
POST https://server/user/{username}/password/request
```

This can (but it's no must) create a sub resource for every password request that is only accessible when authenticated. So you could expose a REST style URL where a user could get all password requests issued over time.

The last functionality to change the password is quite easy now because we have the password sub resource of the user we can issue a `POST` request on the password resource:

```
POST https://server/user/{username}/password
```

Comment: I like how you added "request" here. Very nice! :)